# Unable to select MonoDevelop to open XML file from Unity project

Tags: unity, android, xml, monodevelop

I am developing games in Unity but I have encountered a problem. After updating Unity I can no longer find MonoDevelop for editing XML files like my Android Manifest:

[image: Screenshot showing AndroidManifest.xml selected in Unity editor, with a blank white page icon, captioned "Not find Monodevelop"]

[image: Screenshot of External Tools dialog, where MonoDevelop does not show up as one of the options for an External Script Editor]

[image: Screenshot of Scripts folder showing many C# files displaying their icons normally, captioned "But here is not a problem"]

Comment: Mono Develop no longer comes with Unity. The default is now Visual Studio. Look here for more detail: https://codeburst.io/unity-to-discontinue-support-for-monodevelop-in-its-new-version-release-6a7cfeda1fa5

Try using Rider (https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2017/08/30/getting-started-rider-unity/)

Answer (score 1):

MonoDevelop was phased out  in version 2018.1. You now need to use something different, like Visual Studio.